# Include headers of both base and inherited class in main

Tags: c++

I have a class `calendar` and a class `extendedCalendar` that inherits from `calendar`

I want to be able to create objects of both classes in main, so i include both of their headers in `main.cpp` :

```
#include "calendar.h"
#include "extendedCalendar.h"
```

The problem is that `extendedCalendar.h` also has `#include "calendar.h"` in its header so compiler gives me an error:

> 'calendar' : 'class' type redefinition

How can i circumvent this ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use include guards in your headers.

```
//extendedCalendar.h
#ifndef EXTENDED_CALENDAR
#define EXTENDED_CALENDAR

//body of header

#endif

//calendar.h
#ifndef CALENDAR
#define CALENDAR

//body of header

#endif
```

If you're using MSVS, you can use

```
#pragma once
```

Comment: should i include it in main.cpp ?

Comment: @Michael, no only in the headers. Note that the `pragma` is not portable. If you're compiling on multiple platforms, you should use include guards.

Comment: you've been consistently answering my questions with great answers. you should start accepting donations ;)

Comment: @Michael stay long enough on StackOverflow, and you'll find there are a group of people that provide regular answers to questions on a specific tag. :)